# How to append rows to different variables before appending to a list in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a input file like this

input:

```
20

23 121 20

35 113 11

12 15 142

17 90 110

58 12 198

......
```

I want to create to a list with numbers in each row assigned to a different variable. I'm trying to do like this..

```
def prog(inStr):

    input = inStr.split()

    N = int(input[0])
    list = []

    for i in range(N):
        row1 = int(input[1])
        row2 = int(input[2])
        row3 = int(input[3])
        r = prog(row1, row2, row3)
        list.append(r)
```

But it's not working as it should, if executed like this..

```
row1 = int(input[i*3+1])

row2 = int(input[i*3+2])

row3 = int(input[i*3+3])
```

Throws an error, index out of range.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: What are you passing as an argument to `prog`?

Comment: sorry! didn't get you. I am defining a class for prog, as that what you mean.

Comment: Why is `prog` trying to call itself, especially with the wrong number of arguments? This makes no sense whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than split your input on all whitespace, split it on *line separators* first:

```
def prog(inStr):
    lines = inStr.splitlines()
    N = int(lines[0])
    result = []
    for index in range(N):
        row1, row2, row3 = map(int, lines[index + 1].split())
```

If `inStr` came from a file or standard input, you could read from the input directly:

```
from itertools import islice

test_count = int(next(fileobj))
result = [r(*map(int, line.split())) for line in islice(fileobj, test_count)]
```

This uses a list comprehension, [`itertools.islice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to give a hard limit the number of iterations, and argument unpacking to produce the result list.

Comment: Upvote +1, but do not use built-in function name as variable name e.g. `input`.

Comment: @VivekSable: I was focusing on other improvements first, but yes, `input` is not a good variable name.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to parse a 2D array from a file, you could parse the file into a Numpy 2D Array called A in the following way:

```
import numpy
f=open("file.txt")
i=0
for line in f:
    line=line.rstrip("\r\n")
    if line!="":
        if i==0:
            N=int(line)
            A=numpy.zeros((N, 3))
        else:   
            splittedRow=line.split()
            A[i-1,0]=int(splittedRow[0])
            A[i-1,1]=int(splittedRow[1])
            A[i-1,2]=int(splittedRow[2])
        i+=1    
print A
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a try

```
rows = inStr.split('\n')
count = int(rows[0])

for row in rows[1:]:
    yourList.append(prog(*map(int, row.split())))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very unclear what you're trying to do, but I suspect it's the usual programming competition thing, where you can do this:

```
N = input()
for _ in range(N):
    a, b, c = map(int, raw_input().split())
    print(a, b, c)
```

Of course instead of printing `a`, `b` and `c`, do with them what you're supposed to do.

Or if you really want to collect the input as a list of rows:

```
N = input()
rows = [map(int, raw_input().split()) for _ in range(N)]
```